# Visual Studio Code search across files (find in files) is not working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.31.1 in  MacOS 10.13.6. I open VSCode, I open a folder of text files, and I press command-option-F, or use *Edit* -> *Find in Files*. I search for a string that I know for sure exists in multiple text files in the open folder, and it says it can't find it.

Searching across files works if I have the folder open and have each and every single file open as a tab, which is rather pointless. Is there a way to search across files without actually having them all open as tabs?

I think it was because I opened a folder on Google Drive File Stream. It works fine on local files.

Comment: Maybe you should open new issue on github https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: I have the same, but for code on a server, works locally, not remotely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue on Mac, seems like it was related to Google Drive. once I moved the files on my local drive the search worked fine.

Comment: Yeah it was Google Drive (probably) as I found out later but I forgot to update my question.

Comment: Met the same issue with my google drive here as well. Making folder available "offline" not solving the issue. Guess only a github is an option.

Comment: There is definitely still some issue here... it is still not finding strings I know to be in files I have open both in the left list and also tabs on top. Returns nothing on search, but then when I click on tab heading to reload file from disc that hasn't been opened today, and re-do same search, it then finds string in the file I just "touched". This appears to be Windows network share files (using mapped network drive).

Answer (score 161):

In my case, this was caused by me accidentally toggling the "Search only in Open Editors" option.

[image]

Comment: similar case for me: The icon below was activated "Use exclude settings and ignore files" and the relevant file was in the `.gitignore`

Comment: Just for those with similar problem, icon is turning highlighted and it's so easy to click by accident and leave it "ON" without noticing.  Oh boy, this was pain ... Thank you @Jonathan !

Comment: It is difficult to figure out that open file option is on or off

Comment: Given how many ppl are looking for help in this matter, it proves the UX of this part is really poor. Also - am I the only one that find search in VS code subpar to most other IDEs/editors?

Comment: I wish VS Code made it more obvious this was switched off/on. It's pretty ridiculous that I'm been stymied for the last two or three days because of an errant mouse click. I miss Atom.

Comment: Looks like VS Code added a text message below to indicate when "searching only in open files" is enabled, and a text "disable" button too. It took me some time to notice it, but at least there is some text indication now.

Comment: UI smell: that "searching only in open files" message is poorly placed. It should go immediately under the "files to include" textbox, not under the "files to exclude" textbox. It's current location is makes it easy to miss.

Answer (score 18):

It could be that the search is looking into all folders (including node_modules ones), so as it is too big, the search never ends

To fix that, you can list all folders that you want to exclude of the search, to do that, open your vscode settings (`ctrl` + `,`) type "Search: Exclude" in the search box and add your folders. (Btw some are already added by default)

Besides, remember to enable that filter in your search, this is simple, just toggle on the gear button in your search section

[image: Exclude button search]

If you are still not sure about what to do, take a look in this briefly gif

[image: Exemple setting things up]

Answer (score 14):

Had this same issue, the search functionality was only working for files that were open in the editor. My issue was that VS Code had an update downloaded and ready to update, so I just restarted VS Code, let the update finish and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 6):

Check out your vs code settings. It excludes some folders by default e.g. node modules.

Comment: Yep! Looks like by default "Use ignore files" is turned on. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify the comment above, by default VSC search ignores everything that is excluded by .gitignore. That is a separate setting from the one that controls ignoring commonly excluded folders like node_modules. To turn it off, in Preferences, search for ".gitignore" and uncheck

Comment: The precise settings are:
-  "Search: Use Global Ignore Files" and
-  "Search: Use Ignore Files"

  --> set these both to UNCHECKED (i.e. disabled) to get your search fully working.

These settings will ensure that files listed in .gitignore are INCLUDED in the search.

Answer (score 5):

The problem for me was that the files were found in directories listed in `.gitignore`, and the search excluded files from `.gitignore`.

While some other answers/comments mentioned this, I thought it made sense to compile the options in a clear answer. You have a few options:

1. Turn off "Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files" on the bottom right corner of the search feature. This affects the particular search, and is recommended if you want to be flexible:
   [image]
2. Uncheck "Search: Use Ignore Files" in the settings (and potentially "Search: Use Global Ignore Files" too). This affects your settings, rather than just this search. You could do this for your user or workspace settings, if you'll consistently want to exclude the ignore files:
   [image]
3. Remove the file/folder from `.gitignore` (not recommended, since you put it in the `.gitignore` file for a reason)

Note: I was connecting to a remote server with VSCode.

Answer (score 4):

Go to settings, search "Search" , there will be list to exclude folders.
Remove item which might be accidentally got included, which might causing search item in all directory is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I initially wrote this answer describing a confusing "inverted" behavior of the `Search only in Open Editors` option/button.

However, after playing around it turns out that what the GUI was showing was not "in sync" with what the search results were returning. Toggling the options a few times appears to have fixed things.

So if your search doesn't appear to be returning any results, I would suggest toggling the `Search only in Open Editors` and `Use Exclude Settings and Ignored Files` options.

Otherwise, for information, here is my previous answer:

---

VS Code has an extremely confusing "inverted" interface when it comes to the option `Search only in Open Editors`.

There is also another option which affects how search works in a confusing way: `Use Exclude Settings and Ignored Files`.

The below screenshot shows both:

[image: VS Code Search Options]

Note that:

- `Search only in Open Editors` is OFF
- `Use Exclude Settings and Ignored Files` is ON

With these options I get search results back, with them set the other way around - confusingly - I get nothing.

Important to note:

- If you turn `Use Exclude Settings and Ignored Files` OFF, then VS Code seems to stop searching any files, EXCEPT for those which are currently open in tabs. This is very confusing and not the behavior one would expect. The expected behavior would probably be to search the whole opened Folder/Workspace by default.
- If you turn `Search only in Open Editors` OFF, then only open editors will be searched. This is the "inverted" behavior. My current build of VS Code has the indicator "inverted" for this GUI element. When it looks like it is in the "ON" state, it is actually "OFF". When it looks like it is in the "OFF" state, it is actually "ON'.
- These two things interact in unexpected ways: (This is the behaviour I observed after toggling both buttons a few times. It is different to what I was seeing a few minutes ago.)
- `Open Editors` (looks like) it is OFF, `Use Exclude Settings` (looks like) it is ON, search appears to search whole workspace.
- `Open Editors` (looks like) it is OFF, `Use Exclude Settings` (looks like) it is OFF, search appears to search open tabs only.
- `Open Editors` (looks like) it is ON, `Use Exclude Settings` (looks like) it is OFF, search appears to search whole workspace.
- `Open Editors` (looks like) it is ON, `Use Exclude Settings` (looks like) it is ON, search appears to search whole workspace.

I suspect that when typing / editing the search terms, replace option, and files to include/exclude options, VS Code does not check the state of the option buttons before performing the search. This is likely the source of the bug I was seeing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today. Turns out I had a deprecated setting for advanced RegEx searches `"search.usePCRE2": true,` Once removed, search started working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem on VS Code 1.58.2 / Mac OS 10.15.7

None of the above solutions worked for me, it still keeps saying 'No results found in open editors' no matter what I do.

But I did get it working by changing the 'Search: Mode' in the settings (for the workspace, or any other scope if needed) from '**view**' to '**reuseEditor**'.

Yes, this doesn't fix it if you really want the results in the Explorer tab rather than a completely new editor window, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with searching in a project with git submodules and found that the gitlens add-on defaults to ignore searching any submodules:

[image]

Setting this to 2 or more may address your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue last month, and I was unable to find any solution on the internet. So what I did was that I created a backup of my `settings.json` (not `defaultSettings.json`) file and then cleared its contents and restarted VSCode. It worked, the only downside was I had to reconfigure some of my settings though, although it was totally worth it, since this was a big pain in the a** for me.

You can search for `settings.json` by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had somehow gotten my Explorer set on a subfolder of my project. Closing VS Code and reopening the workspace reset everything and search worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed mine by removing files in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was **files with no extensions** I was not able to find. Once I added those files an extension, I was able to find them via the search feature.

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS Code 1.79.2 on a Windows Server OS and editing some Python and experienced a similar reduction in the number of results found. It turned out Find in Selection icon in search text overlay was highlighted. Tried to print it but tooltip would then disappear - so improvised and overlaid some text on image.. See below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to save the file once more. The effect after I searched was visible in the application, also in `git diff`, but not in the Studio Code search. Not in the full text search and also not in the search in the file. When I saved the file again, the effect was then same everywhere. I did put a space somewhere in this file. Then saved and then removed again.
Git diff helped me find the file.

- Version: 1.81.0
- Electron: 22.3.18
- OS: Linux x64 6.2.0-26-generic

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to search using "Ctrl+F" it didn't search properly and not resulted any output.

Instead I tried "Ctrl+Shift+F" and it did proper search and resulted output.

It's on Win 11, VSCode Version 1.85.1

Answer (score 0):

Using `code-insiders-1.88.0-1710157206.el8.src`, I had to:

1. Manually open each editor (tab):

   1. > [image]
   2. > [image]
2. Reselect the filter:

   1. > [image]
   2. > [image]
   3. > [image]

After that, the list would be populated.